# .htaccess rewriterule 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this might already exist but i can't seem to find out the answer after searching for a while now.

well this is what i want:

```
http://example.com/user/blitzen12
http://example.com/properties/1
```

.htaccess file

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^user/([^\/]*)\/?$ ./user/user-page.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^properties/([^\/]*)\/?$ ./properties/property-page.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the problem is when I try access `http://example.com/properties/1` while the first rewriterule is present I got 500 internal error.
but when I try to remove or comment the first rewriterule everything is working fine.

or when I try to access `http://example.com/agents/blitzen12` while the 2nd rewriterule is present I got the same error and it's working fine when I remove the 2nd rewriterule

apache full error logs

```
[Thu May 22 14:59:12.940137 2014] [core:error] [pid 216:tid 1668] [client ::1:58929] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

can someone point out what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `./` at the start of the second part of your rules.OR set your rewritebase to just `/`. You should also find the option to set the maximum number of redirects your htaccess will allow before giving up.

Comment: Thanks it works. I'm so damn stupid. I've tried removing `/` and it's not working but I didnt think of removing `./`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `./` from your two RewriteRules should do the trick.